# For each occurence of word in striing, replace with random word from array

Tags: php, regex

Here is current code :-

```
 function randommacrofunc($string){

  $RandomTextArray =  array("Name","Think","Person","Apple","Orange","bananna"); 
  $count = substr_count($string, '{random}');
  $i = 0;
  //re:
  if ($i <= $count){
     shuffle($RandomTextArray);
     $string = str_replace('{random}', $RandomTextArray[$i], $string, $i);

     $i++;
     //goto re;
  }

  return $string;
}
```

My goal is to replace each occurrence of `{random}` in a string by a word fetch from the `$RandomTextArray` array. when loading, its replacing right word, but with all the same word. Exemple : `{random}{random}{random}` return `AppleAppleApple`  bit I want it return `ApplePersonThink`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to raplace wit random array value:

```
<?php
 function randommacrofunc($string){

 $RandomTextArray =  array("Name","Think","Person","Apple","Orange","bananna");

 $count = substr_count($string, '{random}'); // count number of `{randome}` in the string

 for ($i = 0;$i<$count;$i++){ // iterate for loop till the count reach
       $string = preg_replace('/{random}/',  $RandomTextArray[rand(0,(count($RandomTextArray)-1))], $string, 1);
 }
 return $string; // return final replaced string
}

$string = '{random} string {random} string {random} string {random} string {random} string {random}';
echo randommacrofunc($string);
```

Comment: it will work for random replacement. Mine is for sequential replacement.

Comment: @btc4cash  i gave my solution based on sequential replacement (one-by-one and then repeate)

Answer (score 0):

While your task does not demand regex because your targeted substring is static (`{random}`), I do prefer the concise syntax of `preg_replace_callback()`.

Flipping your lookup array in advance will simplify the replacement process.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MLvjt))

```
$randoms = array_flip([
    "Name",
    "Think",
    "Person",
    "Apple",
    "Orange",
    "bananna"
]); 

$string = 'this {random} is {random} and {random} obviously.';

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '~\{random}~',
         function() use ($randoms) {
             return array_rand($randoms);
         },
         $string
     );
```

Possible Output:

```
this Name is Person and Orange obviously.
```